# Python Requests returning 500

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-requests

I am writing a program that will POST a file to a website that is making me go through a few steps to get the file properly uploaded. In the first step, I perform a simple POST which alerts the site that a file will be uploaded and returns a URL to an Amazon S3 bucket, along with some more response content. The next step is to POST the file to the URL returned in step one, and this is where things break. My code is as follows:

```
import requests
import os
from collections import OrderedDict

etlmig = <token>
auth = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + etlmig}
path = <path>
file = os.listdir(path)[0]
stats = str(os.stat(path + '\\' + file)[6])

params1 = {'name': file, 'size': stats}
r1 = requests.post('https://......', headers=auth, data=params1)
print r1.status_code #This returns a 200
content1 = r1.json()
contentlist1 = content1.values()

url = str(contentlist1[1])

contentlist2 = list(contentlist1[2])
contentlist3 = contentlist1[2].values()

aws1 = str(contentlist2[0])
aws2 = str(contentlist3[0])
suc1 = str(contentlist2[1])
suc2 = str(contentlist3[1])
acl1 = str(contentlist2[2])
acl2 = str(contentlist3[2])
key1 = str(contentlist2[3])
key2 = str(contentlist3[3])
sig1 = str(contentlist2[4])
sig2 = str(contentlist3[4])
pol1 = str(contentlist2[5])
pol2 = str(contentlist3[5])
fil1 = str(contentlist2[6])
fil2 = str(contentlist3[6])

m = OrderedDict()
m[key1] = key2
m[acl1] = acl2
m[fil1] = fil2
m[aws1] = aws2
m[pol1] = pol2
m[sig1] = sig2
m[suc1] = suc2

course = {'file': open(path + '\\' + file, 'rb')}

r2 = requests.post(url, data=m, files=course)
```

From here the code waits about 45 seconds and then `r2.status_code` returns a 500 error.  I'm not sure how to proceed since a 500 error is a general error that doesn't point me in a good direction to find my mistake.

Also, if anyone has any suggestions for how to parse the JSON content into the format it is eventually used in in a faster way, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue lay in the fact that there was a URL included in the response headers to `r2`.  Requests was trying to follow this URL, but did not have the proper endpoint or authorization and was therefore returning the 500 error.  By changing `r2` to

```
r2 = requests.post(url, data=m, files=course, allow_redirects=False)
```

the issue was resolved.